# Why are Endermen walking around my house at day?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't mean that they walk IN the house.

After a long strip mining trip (day 18 IIRC, Normal Difficulty), I started building a new house, when suddenly.... 3 Endermen appeared far on the horizon, walking towards me.
It was noon, and it wasn't raining; I thought Endermen would teleport somewhere else because of the sun, but they kept walking/teleporting on my direction as if they were planning to kill me!

They walked past me **phew**, and went on forward until they reached the ocean, then they teleported back near my house (100-50 blocks away).

I'm wondering if this is because the game wants me to go to the End, or perhaps I may be near a dungeon?
I read the wiki, and it does not explain this behavior, and it didn't happen ever before 1.8

Answer (score 3):

Endermen spawn at night, but they are unaffected by daylight. Their teleportation is much more active during the night, and if you attack them during the day, they will more likely teleport away from you than fight you.

Mobs only spawn near the player, so there's no real significance to them hanging around near you during the day.

Comment: "Mobs only spawn near the player" - This isn't *entirely* true; except in the case of a mob spawner, mobs will not spawn within 24 blocks of a player, however, mobs despawn randomly outside 32 blocks of a player, and immediately despawn 128 blocks away from a player, so it is *partially* true.

Comment: Day does affect them. I've seen endermen turn red and die during the day, when they weren't being attacked.

Comment: @J.Musser the only things that should affect them during the day are fire, lava, and rain.

Answer (score 0):

Endermen don't die during the day, just water and the usual effects hurt them. You probably just got a really weird pathing on them, then when they went into the ocean they teleported to the nearest dry land that happened to be near your house